# Power Query - repeat process of adding and dropping connections

Tags: excel, excel-2010, powerquery, vba

Each month I carry out a process where I add the previous months' forecast spreadsheets to a forecast summary spreadsheet's workbook queries, append them all (they have the same columns) and then delete the prior-previous months' data connections from the workbook queries. E.g. add division 1 month 6, division 2 month 6, division 3 month 6 etc. Append then delete division 1 month 5, division 2 month 5 and division 3 month 5.

The reason for deleting the prior-previous months' data connections is because Excel 2010 and Power Query cannot seem to handle more than 3 months worth of spreadsheets, throwing a system out of memory error on many occasions. The reason I need previous months' data is because I compare that to the current months' data to show differences between the two months.

What I want to do is automate the process of adding tables to my workbook queries and deleting tables from my workbook queries. Is this possible?

Comment: I think this will give you an idea for your project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgwXt4LVmsU

Comment: @virtualdvid thanks, I've watched that and I'll try and see if it works this week. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: Please let me know. I will try too, because it looks very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Division and Month can be identified from your file names, and they are all in one folder or subfolders, then I would start from Get Data or New Query / From Folder.  I would then Edit the Query to filter the list of files down to just the ones you want to load, then hit the **Combine Files** button (on the **Content** column header).

That will generate the whole Function and Parameter setup for you in the Query Editor.  You just need to add the Steps to suit your requirements and you are done.

Refresh performance should be as good as your manual method - it will only open the files that get through your filter criteria.

Once you get that all set up, there will not be any manual admin required - just hit Refresh.

Comment: Hello Mike, this achieves the quicker combination than the way I was doing it so very good but just not quite complete - if I want to pass this on to someone who doesn't know what's going on I just want them to be able to change the month somewhere and power query just look at that month's folder for the data they need. I'll follow @virtualdvid's video to see if I can create the code more manually so that it at least achieves the overall goal better.

Comment: For that scenario, I would add a table in Excel with a single row for the month required, add a Query to read that table, then apply that as a filter by adding a Merge Queries step using the Join Kind: Inner (only matching rows).  Your colleague only has to change that one row in the new Excel table.

Comment: I finally implemented this and even though I haven't gotten the hang of just having it look at a different folder at the change of a variable, this does a a great job of getting close.